# How to run multiple functions (input dependent on prev function) with python asyncio?

Tags: python-asyncio

I have 2 dataframes which I need to process separately with replace() before merging them together. In my actual use-case, there are more functions to be applied to each dataframe before the final step which is merging the dataframes.

```
# replace function
def replace(df, old_value, new_value='above 60'):
    df.age = df.age.replace(old_value, new_value)

    return df

# dataframes
dfx = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': ['11', '19', '22', '30', '24', '27', '67'],
    'group': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B'],
    'count':[3,5,2,1,4,5,2]
})
dfy = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': ['11', '19', '79', '30', '24', '27', '15'],
    'group': ['D', 'D', 'D', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'F'],
    'count':[7,5,6,1,5,5,8]
})
```

my code to run asynchronously:

```
import asyncio

async def do_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(
        do_after(1, replace(dfx, '67')))

    task2 = asyncio.create_task(
        do_after(2, replace(dfx, '79')))

    final_task = asyncio.create_task(
        do_after(3, pd.merge(dfx, dfy, how='inner', on='age')))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    # Wait until both tasks are completed (should take
    # around 3 seconds.)
    await task1
    await task2
    await final_task

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    return pd.DataFrame(final_task)

await main()
```

**[OUTPUT]:**

```
started at 09:25:18
        age group  count
0        11     A      3
1        19     B      5
2        22     C      2
3        30     C      1
4        24     B      4
5        27     C      5
6  above 60     B      2
        age group  count
0        11     A      3
1        19     B      5
2        22     C      2
3        30     C      1
4        24     B      4
5        27     C      5
6  above 60     B      2
  age group_x  count_x group_y  count_y
0  11       A        3       D        7
1  19       B        5       D        5
2  30       C        1       F        1
3  24       B        4       E        5
4  27       C        5       D        5
finished at 09:25:21
```

Looking at the last table below, the tables have been merged without the replace() applied to them.

 1. Why is that?

 2. How do I return the merged table as a pandas dataframe?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am actually wondering why to do this asynchronously, if you want those 3 functions to be synchronous? use one function call sequentially the 3 steps, no?

Comment: It's because the process takes too long in my actual use case. Prior to the final task which is merging the dataframes, i want the tasks to run at the same time. Perhaps my example should another task before final task

Comment: Since `replace()` is not an async function when you create tasks as `asyncio.create_task(do_after(1, replace(dfx, '67')))` you are actually running the `replace` function in the invocation of `replace(dfx, '67')`. You are essentially passing the `df` into `do_after`. Ultimately, this code is not doing what you think it is doing. Regardless of it though, `asyncio` is not for these types of computation-heavy operations, and even if you do fix your current code it won't make much of a difference. `asyncio` is intended to be used for IO operations; network input/output, disk input/output, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, this is not the typical workload that will benefit, at all, from async programming. One could use asyncio to orchestrate calls work in parallel dataframes in different subprocess, and maybe that could make a difference (but the most optimized operations in pandas, numpy echo-system will make use of all CPU cores, so even in this case, the gains might be negligible).

That said,  the way to ensure ordered execution in asyncio workloads is not to create tasks at all, and simply use inline `await` expressions:

```
async def main():
    ...
    await replace(dfx, '67')
    await replace(dfx, '79')
    await pd.merge(...)
    print("done")
```

If any steps can actually be run in parallel, then one can await for an
`asyncio.gather` call into which all these steps passed at once.